# How to be notified about a painting completion?

Tags: java, eclipse, paint, draw2d

Does anyone know how to get notified when

```
void org.eclipse.draw2d.UpdateManager.paint(GC gc) {
    performUpdate(new Rectangle(gc.getClipping()));
}
```

is executed?
`org.eclipse.draw2d.DeferredUpdateManager.performUpdate(new Rectangle(gc.getClipping())` works asynchronously.

I looked at `org.eclipse.draw2d.UpdateListener` but it doesn't have a method which notifies about a painting completion.